# What is this type of design called when vectors are superimposed with bitmaps?

Tags: vector, effects, style-identification, adobe-after-effects, style

The old Microsoft Campaign ads of *Your Potential Our Passion* showed white lines running through bitmapped video. Most probably this is made in **After Effects**.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GT7QQYzrWog

Do the white lines in itself have a name of the type of design? Is there a general term for superimposing such "vectors" in bitmaps (photos / videos)?

**EDIT** A Few Screenshots:

[image: Vector and Bitmap together Microsoft]
[image: Microsoft Your Potential Our Passion]

Answer (score 1):

The practice of drawing on frames of a film is called **[Rotoscoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotoscoping)**.

Specifically, manually altering each frame of a video to include previously absent visuals. This is not only used for things like drawing on film, but special effects as well.

Comment: THanks! But I dont think this is simple Rotoscoping. Had this been just the line drawn animation, I would've agreed with you. I want to know the term for the **coexistence** of both the vector (could be rotoscoped) and the bitmap (moving video footage)

Comment: What you are describing, the samples you've added **are** rotoscoping.  Rotoscoping is the technique. Within that technique there are many styles, just like all artwork.

Comment: I Agree with you! I'm asking for this specific "style". I'll add more examples.

Comment: Not all styles have a specific name.

Comment: Yep! Hence the question! To verify beyond all doubt!

Comment: If I had to give the style a name it would be "line art" but that term is sufficiently broad and vague to cover styles much different than this, the only real tying characteristic being the emphasis on the "line" aspects of the artwork.